# Apache Spark / PySpark, defining custom JSON Schema for Dynamic Keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bunch of JSON files, and suppose each have the following structure:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "key": "bob"
    },
    "results": {
        "bob": { ... }
    }
}
```

Where by some unfortunate reason, while the structure of the JSON is fairly consistent, there is one dynamic key under "results". Defining the schema for under the `fields` is fairly straight-forward to me.

So, for several JSON files, the final schema might be:

```
fieldSchema = StructField(...)
resultSchema = StructField("results", StructType([StructField("bob", ...)]))
finalSchema = StructType([fieldSchema, resultsSchema])
```

Where the problem is this line: `StructField("bob", ...)`

Obviously, `bob` is not the key I'm looking for. This `name` for the `StructField` would ideally be some kind of wildcard character, regex pattern, or worst case, some dynamic field based on other fields.

I'm a newbie to Spark and have been scouring the documentation and historical StackOverflow posts, but I've been unable to find anything.

**Long story short, I want to be able to pass some kind of wide net for the `name` parameter in StructField to encompass a variety of different keys, similar to a regex pattern.**

Comment: try to set up resultsSchema as a MapType first and then convert it to StructType later if needed.

Comment: @jxc I am a great big fool. That should work. Thank you, I was not able to come across that in my search.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and am very new to PySpark. Please could you post an example of how you got this working?